# how to create, read and write file in ionic native

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am looking for file operation like create, read and write text or logs in to file, i have a lot research but i haven't find any proper example to do so. this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) gives the examples but when i use that in typescript file i got errors like **[ts] Property 'requestFileSystem' does not exist on type 'Window'.**

examples like

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt' 
        // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt' 
        writeFile(fileEntry, null);

    }, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);



function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt). 
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file write...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        // If data object is not passed in, 
        // create a new Blob instead. 
        if (!dataObj) {
            dataObj = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' });
        }

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

is there something which is missing? or i was doing it in a wrong-way? please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use [**Ionic native File plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/).

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file 
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Comment: Can you give me example or link of example? There is just a theory , not a proper example.